# What does || exactly Mean?

Tags: ruby

Recently I saw code like

```
i < 0 ||
```

I wonder what is "||" exactly mean? How to say that in english?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `||` operator is similar to the keyword `or` but is different from the keyword `or` in extremely important ways. Below are two great write-ups on the topic, comparing the two and showing you how to use either one:

- http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/
- New version, with video: http://devblog.avdi.org/2014/08/26/how-to-use-rubys-english-andor-operators-without-going-nuts/

---

The most important thing to note in what Avdi says, is that `||` cannot be used for flow control, whereas `or` can be.

For example...

```
a = :value
c = b || a
#de Since `b` is undefined/null, `c` will be set to `:value`

c = b || puts("Failure!") #de This will raise an exception!

c = b or puts("Failure!") #de Will set `c` to `NilClass` and output "Failure!"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What a thorough answer for my question. I would go through the materials you provide.

Answer (score 2):

Logical "or"

`A || B` is `true` when either `A` is true *or* `B` is true, or when both `A` *and* `B` are true.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot! And thanks for your link.